# Python - Update Value in one dictionary based on input from another

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to figure out a way to manipulate one dictionary based on the input of a second dictionary. I am working on an exercise that simulates a vending machine. Based on the code below, my intent is to update the coin_stock dictionary based on the one of the options picked from the coin dictionary. For example if 'n' is chosen in menu_str, this means I have deposited a nickle. This would mean my coin_stock['nickles'] should be updated from 25 to 26. I am trying to generalize the code to update coin_stock when any of the coin options are entered in menu_str. I am pretty new to python. I have tried different things, but the code below is as close as I could get.

```
coin_stock = {'nickles':25, 'dimes':25, 'quarters':25, 'ones':0, 'fives':0}    
coin = { 'n': 5, 'd': 10, 'q': 25, 'o': 100, 'f': 500}

while True:

    menu_str = input("Indicate your deposit:")

    if menu_str in coin:
        if coin[menu_str] == 'n':

            coin_stock['nickles'] += 1

        if coin[menu_str] == 'd':
            coin[menu_str] = coin_stock['dimes']
            coin[menu_str] += 1

        if coin[menu_str] == 'q':
            coin[menu_str] = coin_stock['quarters']
            coin[menu_str] += 1

        if coin[menu_str] == 'o':
            coin[menu_str] = coin_stock['ones']
            coin[menu_str] += 1

        if coin[menu_str] == 'f':
            coin[menu_str] = coin_stock['fives']
            coin[menu_str] += 1

        coin_stock['nickles']+= 1
        print(coin_stock['nickles'])
```

Comment: You appear to be confusing *count* with *value.* There is no reason to assign from `coin_stock` to `coin`, because those two collections store different things.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements will not work, e.g. for a nickel, `menu_str` is `n` so `coin[menu_str]` is `5`. Just checking `menu_str` should do what you want

```
coin_stock = {'nickles':25, 'dimes':25, 'quarters':25, 'ones':0, 'fives':0}
coin = { 'n': 5, 'd': 10, 'q': 25, 'o': 100, 'f': 500}

while True:
    menu_str = input("Indicate your deposit: ")
    if menu_str == 'n':
        coin_stock['nickles'] += 1
    elif menu_str == 'd':
        coin_stock['dimes'] += 1
    elif menu_str == 'q':
        coin_stock['quarters'] += 1
    elif menu_str == 'o':
        coin_stock['ones'] += 1
    elif menu_str == 'f':
        coin_stock['fives'] += 1
    else:
        print("Exiting on invalid coin ({})".format(menu_str))
        break

print(coin_stock)
```

Comment: `menu_str in coin.keys()` converts the dictionary to a list of keys and linear-scans the list. Better to say `menu_str in coin` and check the dictionary for the key directly.

Comment: you don't really need to test `menu_str in coin` either, since the nested `if` will do that. may shallow on layer.

Comment: thanks for the recommendations, I've incorporated them

Comment: This helped! This is exactly what I envisioned in my head, but I guess I made it more difficult than it needed to be. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use this as an opportunity to plug Python's powerful collection types.

#### Keeping Count

Check out the `Counter()` class in the `collections` library of Python's stdlib:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Think of the Counter object as an overpowered dictionary, designed for keeping tally. It's nice for the use case of keeping tally of different coins types in a data store:

```
coin_store = Counter({'nickles': 25, 'dimes': 25, 'quarters': 25, 'ones': 0, 'fives': 0})
print(coin_store)  # Counter({'nickles': 25, 'dimes': 25, 'quarters': 25, 'ones': 0, 'fives': 0})
coin_store['nickles'] += 1
print(coin_store)  # Counter({'nickles': 26, 'dimes': 25, 'quarters': 25, 'ones': 0, 'fives': 0})
```

#### Merging Counters

For the question of finding "a way to manipulate one dictionary based on the input of a second dictionary" we can create a dictionary that contains all keys and values from one data store updated with the keys and values from another:

```
def update_store(coin_store1, coin_store2):
    """Updates the contents of a coin store with values from another store."""
    for coin_type, coin_num in coin_store2.items():
        coin_store1[coin_type] += coin_num

coin_store = Counter({'nickles': 6, 'dimes': 5, 'quarters': 10})
update_store(coin_store, Counter({'quarters': 5, 'ones': 3, 'fives': 10}))
print(coin_store)  # Counter({'quarters': 15, 'fives': 10, 'nickles': 6, 'dimes': 5, 'ones': 3})
```

Now you can use something like that in your code to update based on user input. Note: whatever update function you use requires error handling for invalid coin types and values.

#### Python Dictionaries

It's probably worth spending some time to understand the different operations supported by dictionaries, perhaps starting with `.get()` and `.items()`, and moving on to `.update()` and `.copy()`, etc. See them all here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

This should answer your question, and will hopefully get you interested in exploring the other types of collections offered in Python's stdlib as well. Best of luck!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/2573242 when you're ready to dive into dict updates.